# 3-way dimmer switch conundrum

Tags: dimmer-switch, multiway-switch, ground

I just one replaced a Leviton 3-way switch w a 3-way dimmer.  Now, however, the light only goes in when both switches are "up".  I experimented w swapping the 2 traveller wires at their terminals, and the light didn't go on at all.  I suspect this means I have the dimmer at the Load rather than Line switch.  Is this true?  Is there a fix?  Is there a fix other than moving the dimmer to the other switch location?  This is a 1916 house w old solid copper wiring, so the "code-ness" of things is a bit questionable.  (There is, for example, no "green" ground wire in the box).

Addendum:  I'll have to reopen the box for photos (which was a pain to secure the wallplate) but note this is no Romex installation: these are all black cloth-covered solid copper wires, attached in a 4-gang to modern switches -- two of which control, respectively, the 1st & 2nd floor chandeliers, also controlled by two switches in a 3-gang on the 2nd floor.  I put the dimmer on the 1st-floor 3-way for the 1st-floor chandelier.

As to travellers: I installed the wires in the dimmer 3-way exactly as I removed them from the standard 3-way.  I *think* that on testing, I was surprised that w new switch "off" the common was hot, but w switch "on" both  travellers were hot ... but that could be proximity probe not distinguishing bc wires are so close.

Comment: Can you post photos of the wiring in the boxes involved please?

Comment: Are you *sure* you have properly identified the travelers vs the common?  a) the travelers were on the *brass* screws, and b) they are in the same cable.

Comment: Addressed questions by edit of main post.  I'm hoping we can deduce the answer by experience, as I'm deeply reluctant to mess overmuch w this old wiring.

Comment: To be more specific: on the old 3-way, the "common" was on the single screw, and the "travelers" were on the 2 screws on the other side of the switch.  (It's possible, that the original (set of 2) 3-way was wired wrong, but as they worked perfectly, it seems unlikely).

Comment: Further Addendum: my house was built in 1916, before the "Carter System" of 3-way switches was outlawed.  I think it will be simple enough to test whether this is how the thing is wired: at each switch, one of the (disconnected) "travellers" will be hot (the other will be neutral, and the "common" will be each half of the load; this is why it was outlawed: in 1/4 of the switch positions, both sides of the socket will be energized, even though the lamp is off).